# sending mail but no message-id

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

I am getting interesting rejections from my clients mail server when sending a mail with indy-10's tidMessage component saying:

550 Rejected: Message does not contain a Message-ID

I get this even when using indy's own demo app

http://www.indyproject.org/DemoDownloads/Indy_10_MailClient.zip

what do I do to fix this. thanks!

Comment: They are not RFC2822 compliant: (3.6.4) "Though **optional**, every message SHOULD have a "Message-ID:" field"

Comment: Also, are you delivering directly to the mail server with a idSMTP component? AFAIK most MTA add a message-id themselves, it is easier to ensure its uniqueness there than from SMTP clients.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TIdMessage in Indy 10 intentionally omits the 'Message-Id' header when encoding an email to a socket or TStream.  You will have to use the TIdMessage.ExtraHeaders property, eg:

```
IdMessage1.MsgId := '...';
IdMessage1.ExtraHeaders.Values['Message-Id'] := IdMessage1.MsgId;
```

---

**EDIT:**

As a followup for this - `TIdMessage` has now been updated with logic changes in how it handles the "Message-ID" and "In-Reply-To" headers:

https://www.indyproject.org/2016/09/12/logic-changes-in-tidmessage-regarding-message-id-and-in-reply-to-headers/

The `TIdMessage.MsgId` property now generates a "Message-ID" header regardless of whether the email is being saved, streamed, or transmitted.  So you do not need to use the `ExtraHeaders` property anymore.

Comment: Original link: http://indyproject.org/sockets/blogs/changelog/20160912.aspx

Answer (score 6):

It works with Indy9, maybe things haven't cahnged too much in 10:

```
    procedure AddMsgID(AMsg: TIdMessage);
    var
      id: AnsiString;
    begin
      id := GenerateUniqueMsgID;
      AMsg.MsgId := id;
      AMsg.AddHeader('Message-ID=' + id);
      // AMsg.ExtraHeaders.Values['Message-ID'] := id;
    end; // AddMsgID
```

Comment: You do not need to use AddHeader() and ExtraHeaders together.  Use one or the other, not both.

Comment: OK. Commented `ExtraHeaders` out.