# emails with bcc recipients only sent thorugh Indy don't allow to show recipients in Sent Mail

Tags: delphi, smtp, indy, indy10

I send bcc notifications automatic emails. Those are generated by Indy, using also SSL handler since I use smtp.gmail.com.

When I go to Sent Folder and I open one email I see the ccn list empty. This doesn't happen if I create and send an email with bcc recipients directly from gmail.com.

So when sent from Indy through smtp.gmail.com i don't see in sent mail the bcc recipients, if i send from the gmail webmail I see it.

Is there some Indy setting that I am missing?

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496821/sending-mail-but-no-message-id) for example I see that another standard thing (the Message_ID) is missing by default and must be set. Do I need to set something to see this bbc info?

Comment: What is a "ccn notification"?  What are "ccn repicients"?  Are you referring to "CC" instead, ie the `TIdMessage.CCList` property? Please show your code that is filling in the `TIdMessage` component.

Comment: I believe he means BCC. In Italian and probably other languages it could be something alike.

Comment: yes sorry let me update the question, ccn = bcc

Answer (score 1):

It could be that your local smtp client (or maybe gmail smpt) is stripping bcc informations when the message is sent. On gmail side, it could be different sending a mail directly from gmail (which may not use smpt to communicate internally, and anyway doesn't use Indy...) and from Indy through gmail SMTP implementation.

You could trace the communication using something alike Wireshark, although encryption makes it more difficult (you could try to send through a SMTP server which doesn't require encryption, or proxy it), and see if the bcc header is stripped by Indy or by the server. Moreover Indy comes with full source code...

Comment: You can attach one of Indy's `TIdLog...` components to `TIdSMTP` to see what raw data is being sent before/after SSL encrypts\decrypts it.  I can tell you, though, that Indy DOES NOT include a `BCC` header in the sent email (no SMTP client does - that is what makes it "blind"), but does send the BCC recipients to the SMTP server so it knows where to send the email.

Comment: That's explain what happens to the OP, I think. BCC handling has always been a weak side of email RFCs, the lastet 5322 too didn't clarify it although it noted it in its "security considerations". IMHO weakness are: 1) Mail stored in "sent items" may need the whole bcc field as a reminder 2) People sent a bcc mail may need to see why they received it. People used to email clients which doesn't use standard SMTP to communicate with the server may wonder why it acts different than other email servers.
My opinion is that email today should be treated as a whole service, not as separated protocols

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: now that i finally was able to express my self (bcc/ccn) do you have some suggestions on this issue?

Comment: There is nothing you can do about it on your end. As I said earlier, sending an email via SMTP, there is no BCC header in the actual email, so there is nothing for Gmail to store for that field. When using Gmail's web interface, it knows what the original BCC is.  Gmail could dynamically determine the BCC via SMTP by matching the available recipients to the email's TO and CC headers, but that is something Gmail has to do on its end. You have no control over that.

Comment: Maybe he could try to replace the message in sent items with its own via IMAP, maybe setting that gmail account, if possible, not to save a copy of sent messages there to avoid matching the messages.